# JCarousellite: Duplicating items

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using JCarousellite to create simple carousels on a Drupal site.

In my template file I create the list items by looping through an
array. When I try and create a carousel on one of these pages it has
the habit of duplicating items in the list.

Has anybody experienced this? If so, anybody found a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed after breaking down the plugin code it does duplicate some of the items and adds them to the beginning and end of the list.

At some point it seemed that this was causing me a problem, but after testing and examining it seems I was making that up!